# Restore default Windows 7 key bindings

Tags: windows-7

I recently inherited a work laptop from a previous employee. Unfortunately, the person changed all of the key bindings and most of the built-in bindings no longer work. How do I reset/restore the original bindings?

Comment: What keybindings?

Comment: megaultrafacepalm

Comment: All of them. The Caps Lock and CTRL key are swapped. Something as simple as CTRL+P won't print. CTRL+S won't save anything, etc. They are all screwed up, and I can't get ahold of the previous employee to find out what he changed. I also don't want to reinstall Windows since there is a lot of software that I use and it would take too much time to reinstall and configure those.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use [**SharpKeys**](http://www.randyrants.com/2008/12/sharpkeys_30.html) to extract the required registry key from a Windows 7 installation which has not been messed around with and then import it to the one which has been customised.

Comment: @boyla001 you can accept this as the answer with the green checkmark to the left

Answer (score 0):

This might be a different keyboard layout.

Go to Control Panel, Regional and Language Options, Keyboards, and check.